# Setup an App Group for MacOS command line tool?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, command-line-interface, xcode-command-line-tools

I am creating a runloop in a macOS command line tool to create a background service. I need to setup an App Group for this to enable communication with a Finder Extension.

Xcode does not allow to setup an App Group for command line tool.

Is there any way to setup an App Group for macOS command line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually edit the `.entitlements` file of your command line tool in the project.

If you’re unsure about proper syntax, you can create a new regular app target in the project, set up an App Group for it using Xcode interface, then open `.entitlements` and copy/paste “App Group” value to corresponding file in your command line tool target.

[image]

The App Group capability *will* be included in the binary file, but I haven’t verified whether it will actually be honored by the operating system. Maybe there’s a reason it’s not available via Xcode UI for this kind of target.

Comment: I can confirm that the App Groups that are adde this way are honored at least for Distributed notifications.